# Protractor failed after unsuccessful attempt?

Tags: testing, authentication, protractor, sendkeys

I have two test (without angular). First is that test should fail because of wrong credentials. Second test should pass because of right credentials, but protractor won't even fulfill email email form, he just skip it. Any ideas why is this happening?

Also, if I run test separately it works fine.

```html
   
    describe('When clicking on login with bad credentials', function() {
    it('Should login to dashboard', function() {
      browser.driver.findElement(by.id('email')).sendKeys('wrong@example.com');
      browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('pass');
      element(by.id('login')).click().then(function() {
        expect(element(by.id('main-logo')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
      });
    });
  });

  describe('When clicking on login with good credentials', function() {
    it('Should login to dashboard', function() {
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('email')).sendKeys('right@exmaple.com');
      browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('pass@@@');
      element(by.id('login')).click().then(function() {
        expect(element(by.id('main-logo')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: what error are you getting? can you paste the stacktrace?

Comment: That false supposed to be true, but problem is that it didn't automatically input email field, it just skipped it, and in first test it fulfill it normally.

Comment: did you put `browser.ignoreSynchronization=true` since you are using non-angular app?

Comment: Stil nothing. Why in that case first test passed normally? Here is my [error](https://gist.github.com/sasafister/65ef59b1cca776802806ae60229c626e) @igniteram1

Comment: I think that problem is that second time, the field is not selected before sendKeys is triggered.

Comment: I like the way you refer to Protractor as "he" :)

Comment: Could you post the exact complete contents of the test spec file you are executing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would first assure that the element are visible, because it makes sense doing that first before sending input data. Also you can use elementor npm library to try catch what is going wrong with your test case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mention browser restarting option "***restartBrowserBetweenTests: true***" on your conf.js file? If not, try it once.

Hope it will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a non-anguar page, and using `browser.ignoreSynchronization=false`, you will have to perform some kind of wait or ExpectedConditions after you click the login button for this test to ever give consistent results. It may be checking for the logo immediately after clicking, without waiting for the next page to load.

You might trying sending a `.clear()` to the input element before `.sendKeys()`, and make sure your test is correct (typo in right@example.com)